# How can I make my Material React Table responsive without causing a horizontal scroll on the entire table?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a div which has a material-react table(not material UI table). I want to make it responsive.I have tried a lot of different ways but it isnt working for some reason. Whenever I try something the whole table goes into horizontal scroll instead of just the columns inside going into a horizontal scroll.I have fixed the width of the table right now to 1245px which causes the columns to go into the horizontal scroll.

```js
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: "20px",
          overflowX: "auto",
        }}
      >
        <MaterialReactTable
          displayColumnDefOptions={{
            "mrt-row-actions": {
              muiTableHeadCellProps: {
                align: "center",
              },
              size: 120,
            },
          }}
          columns={columns}
          data={tableData}
          enableStickyHeader
          enableStickyFooter
          muiTableContainerProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: "450px",width:"1245px"} }}
          editingMode="modal" //default
          enableColumnOrdering
          renderTopToolbarCustomActions={({ table }) => (
            <Box
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                gap: "1rem",
                p: "0.5rem",
                flexWrap: "wrap",
              }}
            >
              <Button
                color="primary"
                //export all data that is currently in the table (ignore pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.)
                onClick={handleExportData}
                startIcon={<FileDownloadOutlined />}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Export All Data
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled={table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows.length === 0}
                //export all rows, including from the next page, (still respects filtering and sorting)
                onClick={() =>
                  handleExportRows(table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows)
                }
                startIcon={<FileDownloadOutlined />}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Export All Rows
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled={table.getRowModel().rows.length === 0}
                //export all rows as seen on the screen (respects pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.)
                onClick={() => handleExportRows(table.getRowModel().rows)}
                startIcon={<FileDownloadOutlined />}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Export Page Rows
              </Button>
              <Button
                color="error"
                onClick={downloadPdf}
                startIcon={<PrintOutlined />}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Print as PDF
              </Button>
            </Box>
          )}
          options={{
            tableLayout: "auto",
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

I have tried using flex,I have tried setting the width of the div and table to 100% and couple more solutions but doesnt work.